# How can I get the Moment album and all the personal albums in my collectionView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, photosframework

I'm trying to use the `Photos Framework`. In my `collectionView`, I would like to display the poster image of the `Camera Roll` and `Personal albums`.

I'm trying to implement the code this way but I still see the same image for each album ... where am I doing wrong?

Here I place my code ... I hope someone can help me

```
//USER ALBUM
@property (nonatomic, strong) PHFetchResult *userAlbum;
@property (nonatomic, strong) PHAssetCollection *assetCollection;
@property (nonatomic, strong) PHAsset *asset;


-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    PHFetchOptions *userAlbumsOptions = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
    userAlbumsOptions.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:YES]];

    self.userAlbum = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeAlbum | PHAssetCollectionTypeMoment  subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeAlbumRegular options:nil];

    for (NSInteger i =0; i < self.userAlbum.count; i++) {
        self.assetCollection = [self.userAlbum objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"%@",[self.assetCollection.localizedTitle uppercaseString]);

        PHFetchResult *fetchResult = [PHAsset fetchKeyAssetsInAssetCollection:self.assetCollection options:nil];
        self.asset = [fetchResult firstObject];
 }
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.userAlbum.count;
}


-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        KCCategoryCell *catCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:categoryCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];

        CGFloat retina = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
        CGSize square = CGSizeMake(catCell.albumImage.bounds.size.width * retina, catCell.bounds.size.height * retina);

        [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageForAsset:self.asset targetSize:square  contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill options:nil resultHandler:^(UIImage * _Nullable result, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
                catCell.albumImage.image = result;
        }];

        return catCell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason to why you're seeing the same image is because you're requesting the same asset for all of your indexes:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    KCCategoryCell *catCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:categoryCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];

    CGFloat retina = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    CGSize square = CGSizeMake(catCell.albumImage.bounds.size.width * retina, catCell.bounds.size.height * retina);

    [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageForAsset:self.asset // <-- Right here
                                               targetSize:square  contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill options:nil resultHandler:^(UIImage * _Nullable result, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
        catCell.albumImage.image = result;
    }];

    return catCell;
}
```

So instead of doing that, do this:

1) Change `@property (nonatomic, strong) PHAsset *asset;` to `@property (nonatomic, strong) PHFetchResult *assets;`

2) Instead of doing this:

```
PHFetchResult *fetchResult = [PHAsset fetchKeyAssetsInAssetCollection:self.assetCollection options:nil];
self.asset = [fetchResult firstObject];
```

Do this:

```
self.assets = [PHAsset fetchKeyAssetsInAssetCollection:self.assetCollection options:nil];
```

3) Lastly, instead of doing this:

```
[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageForAsset:self.asset
                                           targetSize:square contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill options:nil resultHandler:^(UIImage * _Nullable result, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
   catCell.albumImage.image = result;
}];
```

Do this:

```
[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageForAsset:self.assets[indexPath.row]
                                           targetSize:square contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill options:nil resultHandler:^(UIImage * _Nullable result, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
   catCell.albumImage.image = result;
}];
```

To recap:

You're fetching the same image (`self.asset`) over and over again, for all the cells. So, instead, make a property for all of the assets and fetch the right asset for the right cell.

Comment: crash and I don't know why

Comment: What kind of crash..?

Comment: stupid error... solved... excuse me ... your answer is correct!.. thanks for your support!!!